# Asp.net core 2/Angular 4 template build not working

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created project using Asp.net core 2/Angular 4 template that ships whith
.Net core 2 Sdk.

Using `dotnet build` or `dotnet run` it's not generating new dist folder for client side angular project.

I am using visual studio code as editor.

Can i miss any command beacuse of that new build is not generating?

Following is package.json

```
{
  "name": "mcxpricecore",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Use the command `npm run build:dev` or `npm run dev-build`

Comment: error - misssing script : npm run build:dev

Comment: error - misssing script : npm run dev-build

Comment: Show your package.json

Comment: please find package.json in question edit

Comment: Just tey runni g the command `webpack`

Comment: thanks Faisal. it's working as expected.

Comment: if you are using visual studio `ctrl + F5` will build it for you

Comment: I am using visual studio code as editor

Answer (score 1):

After you have created the project using `dotnet new angular` you need to run `npm install` . After that, everything else should work.

Comment: I know that but after changing clientside application new bundle is not generated with dotnet build or dotnet run

Comment: Are you looking under wwwroot? It should be created when you do a dotnet run.

Comment: So what did you change in the client app?  Perhaps if you look in the output when you run the app you'll see a typescript compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you need to set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable to development.

So in the command line run this:

```
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

then when you do dotnet run it will pick up your changes.

Instructions on using multiple environments here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments

Answer (score 0):

follow these two steps.

1) Setting the environment to development

Command line

> set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

PowerShell

> $Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"

2)

> dotnet run

above command will start core project and also start Hot Module Replacement which is can update changed client angular modules without a full page reload. To start Hot Module Replacement in development fix your code block in Startup.cs as bellow

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
        {
            HotModuleReplacement = true,
            HotModuleReplacementEndpoint = "/dist/__webpack_hmr"
        });
} else {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
```